# Connecting JIRA and Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, jira, connector

I am trying to decide on the best connector/plug-in to use for connecting JIRA with SalesForce.  If you have an opinion, please let me know.  So far, the two most inviting products are [ServiceRocket's Connector for Salesforce and JIRA](https://docs.servicerocket.com/display/CFSJ/Connector+for+Salesforce.com+and+JIRA) and [Go2Group's CRM Plug-In](http://www.go2group.com/alm-solutions/atlassian-plugins/jira-plugins/crm-plugin/).

I have 2 main issues: 1) I do not want to give all my Salesforce users access to JIRA.  I know this is ok for Go2Group, but I can't find the relevent info for ServiceRocket.  2) Preferably, any comments made on a JIRA ticket would not be visible to the SalesForce users.

Please let me know if you have used one of these (or any others) and why you chose it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I liked Service Rockets connector a lot more than Go2Group or ZAgile. Pricing wise, Service Rocket was a great deal. Service Rocket is easy to setup as well and you can play around with an eval license before committing to a production license.

http://marketplace.servicerocket.com/product/connector-for-salesforcecom-and-jira

The ease of use was there as well as I felt like Service Rockets connector offered much better connectivity and control over how it interacted with JIRA / SalesForce.

Their documentation has improved over the last year as well and support wise I have never had an issue communicating with them.

I hope this helps in your decision. It was a really tough one for us to make as all three products seem to be on par with each other parity wise.